# Calculator dot function issue android

Tags: java, android-studio, calculator

I am working on a calculator and practicing java and android development. Everything works fine except for the dot function. here is the problem(see the very last dot):
[image]

here are the codes:

```
case R.id.btn_dot:
            if (dotSet) {
                screenTV.append("");
            } else if (isEmpty() || empty) {
                screenTV.append("0.");
                dotSet = true;

                count++;
            } else {
                screenTV.append(".");
                dotSet = true;

                count++;
            }
```

an operand:

```
ase R.id.btn_add:

            if (isEmpty()) {
                screenTV.append("");
            } else if (screenTvGet().endsWith("+")) {
                screenTV.append("");

            } else if (!isEmpty()) {
                screenTV.append("+");
                dotSet = false;
                empty = true;
                resultSet = false;
                count = 0;

            }
            break;
```

and a number:

```
case R.id.btn0:
            if (resultSet) {
                screenTV.append("");
            } else if (isEmpty()) {
                screenTV.append("");
            } else {
                screenTV.append("0");
                empty = false;
            }
```

Finally, the backspace function:

```
case R.id.btn_backspace:

            String screenContent;
            String screen = screenTV.getText().toString();
            int screenMinusOne = screen.length() - 1;
            String screenMinus = String.valueOf(screenMinusOne);


            if (screen.endsWith("."))
                dotSet = false;


            if (isEmpty()) {
                screenTV.setText("");
            } else {
                screenContent = screen.substring(0, screen.length() - 1);
                screenTV.setText(screenContent);
            }
            break;
```

forget about the "count".

I believe you can see the whole picture. now I want somehow when I clear an operand with "BackSpace function" and the previous number has a dot in it, the dot button doesn't just add an '.' or "0." to the screen instead returns null or just adds this "". I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `dotSet`. You don't need it.

Then, similar to how you do this for `btn_add`:

```java
} else if (screenTvGet().endsWith("+")) {
    screenTV.append("");
```

use a regex for `btn_dot` to check if there is a `.` in the last part of the text:

```java
} else if (screenTvGet().matches(".*\\.\\d*")) {
    screenTV.append("");
```

Comment: Thanks, but is it works if there are more than two groups of numbers somthing like "12.34+45+123+56" ?

Comment: @Rklearner I recommend you learn basic regex, so you could answer this yourself. The regex here is looking for a *dot* (`.`) followed by only *digits* (0-9) at the end of the string, which means that it returns `false` for the string you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, man I'm not familiar with regex I need to learn more about it.